# Instantiating template struct inside template function

Tags: c++

This is my code and I'm trying to understand why it won't compile

```
struct Base {};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : Base {};
```

Then in some class

```
template <typename S>
void SomeClass::SomeMethod()
{
  Derived<S>* ptr;          //ok
  ptr = new Derived<S>();   //Compiler error C2760 on Visual Studio 2019
}
```

Is there something wrong with this? Is C2760 a bug?

**Edit:**
error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected 'type specifier'

**Edit2:**
I used .inl files to implement the template (member) functions, included at the end of the .h ones (using ifndef guards). Might this be related to my problem?

Comment: 1) Please copy-paste the error message. We don't, typically, memorize compiler error codes. 2) Please provide [mre].

Comment: The reason why I didn't put it earlier is because I use a translated version of VS and I wasn't sure "type specifier" was the name it uses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it compiled for me, by putting the whole stuff into a single file and defining the function inside the class.